# Address of a class member function

Tags: c++, pthreads, operands

I have a class called CSum which contains a static method who's identifier is:

```
 static double fileProc(string myFile);
```

In my main function I would simply call it by

```
 CSum::fileproc("foo.txt")
```

However, I will like to invoke pthreads on two separate files.  Therefore I need to obtain the address of this method.  I do so by

```
 return1 = pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &CSum::fileProc(file1), NULL);
 return2 = pthread_create(&t2, NULL, &CSum::fileProc(file2), NULL);
```

But I get an error

> lvalue required as a unary '&' operand.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You don't pass parameters, you just give the name of the function. The parameter you want it to get is the next parameter of the `pthread_create`.

Instead of

```
pthread_create(&t2, NULL, &CSum::fileProc(file2), NULL);
```

do

```
pthread_create(&t2, NULL, &CSum::fileProc, file2);
```

Cast types as appropriate. Note that the thread function is supposed to accept a pointer as a parameter, make sure you define it appropriately.

Comment: Great I understand.  The only problem I will get into is typecasting file2 to a pointer since file2 is a type string (it holds the file location)

Comment: @user966349 - yes, it is a problem. You'll have to use a pointer type (pointer to a `string` for example).

Answer (score 0):

`CSum::fileProc(file1)` is an expression that calls the function and gives you the value the function returns as the value of the expression. You are trying to take the address of that value, which you can't, and this won't do what you want.

`&CSum::fileProc` will give you the function pointer, but it does not have the correct signature for use with pthreads. Since pthreads is a C library, it has a very simplistic interface. Your best bet for C++ is to use a higher-level C++ library that uses pthreads underneath (at least on unixes), like boost threads.

If for some reason yoou can't do that, you need to write your own wrappers. To call your function in a separate thread, you would need to write something like:

```
class CSum {
...
    static void fileProcWrapper(void* param) {
        const char* fileName = (const char*) param;
        fileProc(fileName);
    }
...
```

and call it with

```
pthread_create((&t2, NULL, &CSum::fileProc, (void*) file1.c_str());
```

That just gives you the call, mind, the result is thrown away with this code. If you want to collect the result with pthread_join, you have to do a bit more work.

Comment: The return value does matter and I will attempt to do what is needed to get it to work.  If not, then I will modify the function fileProc.  Thank you for your help

Comment: Be sure to read your pthreads documentation carefully when dealing with the return value. If you store the return value in a local variable, you should not pass a pointer to it to pthread_exit. You need to create a dynamic variable (with new) to store your return value.